# Convert sub-folder into separate project without losing history?

Tags: git, gitlab

I have converted a mercurial project with many sub-folders into git (hg-git extension) and it seems to have worked.

I would now like to have each sub-folder as a separate git project so I can better manage permissions etc.

Is it possible to take the history from the main branch and only pass along the relevant changes which happened to each specific sub-folder? For example, my current version control is for the /dags folder overall and I have change history for over a year saved. I would like project_1 to be completely separate from project_2.

```
--/dags
--/dags/project_1
--/dags/project_2
--/dags/project_3
```

Comment: In particular, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17864475/147356).

Comment: Awesome - that worked perfectly, thank you